# What does single means in single 16-bit Unicode character?

Tags: java, data-structures

The definition of char data type in Java is, the char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. My question is what does single means here.

Comment: Its the opposite of `multiple`. One char == one unicode character.

Comment: It means, as opposed to `String` which stores multiple characters.

Answer (score 1):

It stands for one one character only as a 16 bit Unicode character.  As opposed to a 16 bit value which could actually hold two 8 bit ASCII or UTF-8 characters. One in the high order byte and the other in the low order byte.  So there are potentially 65536 possible 16 bit Unicode characters.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more as I'm new to Java.

Comment: All characters have a representative encoding.   Before Unicode, most characters were represented as 8 bit (or 7 bit) values.  So the letter `a` would be encoded as a decimal value of `97`.  But it was eventually realized that 8 bits was insufficient (consider some of the Asian languages for example)  so larger character sets became available.  And often the same value may stand for different characters.  Which is why one must specify different character sets.  So the `single` above was to make certain it was understood that the 16 bit value was one character and not two.